# ISC vs MIT vs Simplified FreeBSD: what is the difference between these licenses?

Tags: licensing, open-source-software

What is the difference between:

- ISC License
- MIT License (Expat)
- BSD 2-Clause License (FreeBSD/Simplified)

The ISC seems to be a simplification of MIT and FreeBSD Simplified after Berne convention.

> This license is functionally identical to the MIT/Expat and the Simplified BSD licenses, discarding some language that was made unnecessary by the Berne convention.

But [answers on this Stack Exchange question recommend avoiding ISC because it is too vague](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157476/isc-license-advice).

But I also see that ISC was *patched* since so it is good to use now:

> Regarding the ISC terminology, Wikipedia states, 'Before accepting the license as a free software license, the Free Software Foundation (FSF) asked for clarification of the text. In July 2007, as a result, "and distribute" was changed to "and/or distribute".' So the license reads, "...modify, and/or distribute..."

I don't know if [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licenses) is up to date and accurate but it seems to show that ISC is more vague about Patent grant, Private use, Sublicensing, TM grant.

Comment: I don't know if it's better to ask the question to opensource.stackexchange.com or law.stackexchange.com. Sorry if it is not the good place.